# How to align social media icons and their tooltip in a bootstrap4 navbar?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, font-awesome

I have a problem to align social icon and their tooltip to the rest of my navbar.
If you see: icons of socials are not in the center of the square and their tooltip aren't under the yellow box. (There aren't in this code, but under image and name the tooltip are centralized and perfectly under the yellow box).
Moreover, how can I distance them?

Sorry for my bad code, but I'm new at HTML and CSS.

I used bootsrap4 for navbar yellow box and font-awesome for the social icon.
[image]
[image]

I have removed some parts about the logo and title.

```css
.container {
    display: flex; /* mi permette di allineare tutti gli elementi*/
    margin: 15;
    padding: 20;
}
.social {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }

/*Allineo elementi lista*/
.social ul{
    display: flex;
}

/*Rimuove i punti*/
.social ul li{
    list-style: none; 
    display: inline-block;
}


/*Il tooltip è il testo che appare quando posizione il mouse su una determinata zona*/
span.tooltiptext{
    /*Aspetto del testo*/
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    background-color:#803c25;
    color:#fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
  

    /*Posizione del fumetto*/
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 100%;
    margin-left: -79px;
    
    /*Effetto sfocatura*/
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

/* Posizione puntatore del tooltip */
span.tooltiptext::after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color:transparent transparent #803c25 transparent;
  }

.social ul li:hover span.tooltiptext{
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}

/*Loghi Social*/

.fa {
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  

.fa-facebook {
  background: #3B5998;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none
}

.fa-tripadvisor {
    background: #00af87;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none
  }
```

```html
<!-- Script di Bootstrap per realizzare lo sfondo della navbar-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    

    <!-- Navbar-->
    <link href="nav.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<body>
        <header>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-warning navbar-dark">
                <div class="container">

                <div class="logo">
                        <a href="gestione.html">
                            <img src="./Immagini/logo.PNG">
                            <span class="tooltiptext"> Login Admin</span>
                        </a>
                </div>

                <div class="nome">
                    <a href="index.html">Il Brigante</a>
                    <span class="tooltiptext">Home</span>
                </div>

                <div class="social">
                    
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a class="fa fa-facebook" target="_blank"></a>

                            <span class="tooltiptext"> Seguici su facebook</span>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a class="fa fa-tripadvisor"target="_blank">
                                </a>

                            <span class="tooltiptext"> Guarda le nostre recensioni</span>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is unstable, please improve your code.

> You can overwrite `Bootstrap CSS` but not by adding that CSS in `bootstrap classes`. REMEMBER IT.

Back to your code, I modified and added some CSS in your code.

I removed `margin-left: -79px;` from your tooltip because it creates a problem in the future.

I added `position: relative` in your `.social ul li` and added `left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);` to your tooltip class for center your tooltip in each block.

I added `d-flex justify-content-center` classes in your `icons` for centering the icons in a block.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  /* mi permette di allineare tutti gli elementi*/
  margin: 15;
  padding: 20;
}

.social {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}


/*Allineo elementi lista*/

.social ul {
  display: flex;
}


/*Rimuove i punti*/

.social ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}


/*Il tooltip è il testo che appare quando posizione il mouse su una determinata zona*/

span.tooltiptext {
  /*Aspetto del testo*/
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: #803c25;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  /*Posizione del fumetto*/
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  /* margin-left: -79px; */
  /*Effetto sfocatura*/
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
}


/* Posizione puntatore del tooltip */

span.tooltiptext::after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent #803c25 transparent;
}

.social ul li:hover span.tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}


/*Loghi Social*/

.fa {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.fa-facebook {
  background: #3B5998;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none
}

.fa-tripadvisor {
  background: #00af87;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none
}
```

```html
<!-- Script di Bootstrap per realizzare lo sfondo della navbar-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<!-- Navbar-->
<link href="nav.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-warning navbar-dark">
      <div class="container">

        <div class="logo">
          <a href="gestione.html">
            <img src="./Immagini/logo.PNG">
            <span class="tooltiptext"> Login Admin</span>
          </a>
        </div>

        <div class="nome">
          <a href="index.html">Il Brigante</a>
          <span class="tooltiptext">Home</span>
        </div>

        <div class="social">

          <ul>
            <li>
              <a class="fa fa-facebook d-flex justify-content-center" target="_blank"></a>

              <span class="tooltiptext"> Seguici su facebook</span>
            </li>

            <li>
              <a class="fa fa-tripadvisor d-flex justify-content-center" target="_blank">
              </a>

              <span class="tooltiptext"> Guarda le nostre recensioni</span>
            </li>

          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Last question: how can I move social icons? I would like to add space between them and move them a little further down

Comment: for space, you can use `margin`

Answer (score -1):

You need to add below css in "a" tag.

```css
    .container {
        display: flex; /* mi permette di allineare tutti gli elementi*/
        margin: 15;
        padding: 20;
    }
    .social {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
      }

    /*Allineo elementi lista*/
    .social ul{
        display: flex;
    }

    /*Rimuove i punti*/
.social ul li{
list-style: none; 
display: inline-block;
list-style-type: none;
}
.social ul li a{
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}

    /*Il tooltip è il testo che appare quando posizione il mouse su una determinata zona*/
    span.tooltiptext{
        /*Aspetto del testo*/
        visibility: hidden;
        width: 120px;
        background-color:#803c25;
        color:#fff;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 6px;
      

        /*Posizione del fumetto*/
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 100%;
        margin-left: -79px;
        
        /*Effetto sfocatura*/
        opacity: 0;
        transition: 0.3s;
    }

/* Posizione puntatore del tooltip */
span.tooltiptext::after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color:transparent transparent #803c25 transparent;
  }

.social ul li:hover span.tooltiptext{
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}

/*Loghi Social*/

.fa {
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  

.fa-facebook {
  background: #3B5998;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none
}

.fa-tripadvisor {
    background: #00af87;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none
  }
```

```html
<!-- Script di Bootstrap per realizzare lo sfondo della navbar-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    

    <!-- Navbar-->
    <link href="nav.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<body>
        <header>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-warning navbar-dark">
                <div class="container">

                <div class="logo">
                        <a href="gestione.html">
                            <img src="./Immagini/logo.PNG">
                            <span class="tooltiptext"> Login Admin</span>
                        </a>
                </div>

                <div class="nome">
                    <a href="index.html">Il Brigante</a>
                    <span class="tooltiptext">Home</span>
                </div>

                <div class="social">
                    
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a class="fa fa-facebook" target="_blank"></a>

                            <span class="tooltiptext"> Seguici su facebook</span>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a class="fa fa-tripadvisor"target="_blank">
                                </a>

                            <span class="tooltiptext"> Guarda le nostre recensioni</span>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
    </body>
```

Comment: please specify which CSS you need to add and add some explanation so, OP knows what is changed in answer and what I need to change in my code